# matplotlib.pyplot has no attribute 'style'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set a style in matplotlib as per tutorial http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

but what I get in return is:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'
```

My matplotlib version is 1.1.1 (and I'm on a Mac running Mavericks). Where are the styles in this version?

thanks!

Answer (score 23):

In ipython notebook I also had to include %matplotlib inline, otherwise I would still get the same error.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Adding `%matplotlib inline` worked for me as well. I do not get the error message `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'` anymore.

Answer (score 22):

> My matplotlib version is 1.1.1

There's your problem. [The `style` package was added in version 1.4](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#style-package-added). You should update your version.

Comment: I upgraded it to 1.4.2, but I get the same results: `'module' object has no attribute 'style'`. If I try to import `style` module from matplotlib itself, as mentioned in some tutorials, it says `ImportError: cannot import name style`.

Comment: @kurtgn Can you please check that the upgrade really worked? (Import matplotlib and then `print matplotlib.__version__`.)

Comment: You were right! The upgrade didn't work.  I still have 1.1.1. This is very weird though, because `pip freeze` says I have matplotlib==1.4.2. I uninstalled matplotlib globally and locally (in virtualenv), in both states `pip freeze` said I had no matplotlib at all, at which point I installed 1.4.2, which turns out to be still 1.1.1. And I'm stuck.

Answer (score 9):

For people using matplotlib 2.x and discovering this question can use the following snippet:

```
import matplotlib.style
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use('classic')   # any style.
```

This is described in the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html). Note the `import matplotlib.style` is important.

Answer (score 7):

I tried all solutions listed on StackOverflow but somehow none of these work for me. Finally I found a method which worked. Following are the details:
**Environment:**
  OS                 : Ubuntu 16
  Python Version     : 3.5. 
  MatPlotLib Version : 2.0.2

**Correct Way of importing 'style module'**

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

The matplotlib help reads:

:func:**`~matplotlib.use`** (ignore syntax as "`" did not work either on command line or script file)
            a function for setting the matplotlib backend.  If used, this
            function must be called immediately after importing matplotlib
            for the first time.  In particular, it must be called
            **before** importing pylab (if pylab is imported).

Somehow without issuing this command, it was not possible to access the 'Style' module.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For MatPlotLib version 3.6.3 and above, the following code to be used to use "seaborn" style as the seaborn has been deprecated since version 3.6:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("seaborn-v0_8")
```