# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'

Tags: python, matplotlib, module

I am using a Mac,

I try to use the ggplot as follow

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

but I am always getting an error like

```
File "/Users/Desktop/code.py", line 4, in <module>
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'
```

I have been checking to find a solution but I don't know where i am making a mistake. Any comment ?

As mentioned blow, I must upgrade the `matplotlib`however, I am getting error 
My python version is 2.7 
so I tried this

```
pip2 install matplotlib
```

and here are the errors

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=1.5.6 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: nose in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.7.egg (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: backports_abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from singledispatch->tornado->matplotlib)
```

Or I tried

```
sudo port install py27-pip
```

and here are the errors

```
Password:
Error: Current platform "darwin 16" does not match expected platform "darwin 15"
Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
OS platform mismatch
    while executing
"mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch
```

or I tried this

```
python get-pip.py
#Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

then

```
pip install matplotlib
```

the errors are the following

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=1.5.6 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: nose in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.7.egg (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: backports_abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from singledispatch->tornado->matplotlib)


pip2 install -U matplotlib
```

or

```
sudo pip2 install -U matplotlib
```

It gives me a lot of error just few lines at the bottom blew

```
('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/zoneinfo', '/var/folders/0y/736q6sd901z27bmpx9nwn_p40000gn/T/pip-r5YiwW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/zoneinfo', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0y/736q6sd901z27bmpx9nwn_p40000gn/T/pip-r5YiwW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz/zoneinfo'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz', '/var/folders/0y/736q6sd901z27bmpx9nwn_p40000gn/T/pip-r5YiwW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0y/736q6sd901z27bmpx9nwn_p40000gn/T/pip-r5YiwW-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz'")]
```

The same if I do with `sudo`

```
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-5PMqIK-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz'")]
```

Comment: Which version of matplotlib is it ?

Comment: @C.Dlp to be honest , I don't know , I don't know how to check it neither I read this one but did not help me to know which versions it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473600/matplotlib-version

Comment: Try this : `from matplotlib.style import use` `use('ggplot')`

Comment: You should update your version of matplotlib : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204646/matplotlib-pyplot-has-no-attribute-style

Comment: run `python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; print(dir(plt))"` and verify that you can see `style` in the diplayed list.

Comment: @ettanany great, I did not see the `style`so I must install it again? actually I am trying to install it by different ways introduced here http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#install-osx-binaries which I am getting error . would you please give me a solution as an answer to upgrade it? I would accept your solution

Comment: @C.Dlp the problem is that I cannot upgrade or install `matplotlib`again. look at above

Comment: Try `pip2 install -U matplotlib` to upgrade your package

Comment: You need to post the last lines which should contain some information about the error

Comment: @ettanany I added above

Comment: try `sudo pip2 install -U matplotlib --ignore-installed six`

Comment: @ettanany  @Learner  now I get this error `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')`any thought how to solve it,

Comment: Try to uninstall matplotlib `pip uninstall matplotlib` and then re-install with correct version `pip install matplotlib==1.4.3`

Comment: @C.Dlp I get this error `"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-hnzCP4-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib'")]`

Comment: Do you use a virtualenv ? In this case delete it and re-install it.

Comment: @C.Dlp I just installed `virtualenv`then `sudo pip uninstall matplotlib` then `sudo pip install matplotlib==1.4.3` which I always get error like `Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-VDR0Gs-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib'")]`

Comment: And with `sudo pip install --ignore-installed matplotlib==1.4.3` ?

Comment: @C.Dlp I get this error  then `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/man'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to do

```
sudo pip2 install -U matplotlib --ignore-installed six
```

You must use **--ignore-installed six** because of the fact that OS ships with six 1.4.1 installed and if one tries to uninstall it (because awscli depends on botocore, botocore depends on python-dateutil, and python-dateutil depends on six >= 1.5) it doesn't have permission to do so because System Integrity Protection doesn't allow even root to modify those directories.

This is highlighted here https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

After you do this, you can check the version of your `matplotlib`as

```
python -c 'import matplotlib; print matplotlib.__version__'
```

If you get the error you mentioned as

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
```

, then it is easy to solve it

> open terminal

Then write `python`

Then

```
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> mpl.get_configdir()
```

Once you know the path, go to the `finder` -----> `Go`
There search for the folder and remove `fontList`

Then run your program again, you will get the warning once more and it is solved. 
Further info, can be found here too for the second part 
[matplotlib taking time when being imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771191/matplotlib-taking-time-when-being-imported)